# Windows Server 2012 HyperV

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, hyper-v-server-2012

I have a server at my company with Windows Server 2008 R2 with 4 VM's for software testing.

**1st Question**
I have access to the new Windows Server 2012. Is HyperV in Server 2012 much better than the one in Server 2008 R2? Or the advantages are more for Data Centers?

**2nd Question**
With Windows Server Standard I can only have 4 virtual machines running or I can only have 4 virtual machines sharing the host key?
Can I have more than 4 VM's with Server Standard Edition or I need a Data Center Edition to have 6-8 VM's?

Thsnks.

Comment: CSeven, welcome to ServerFault. Note that both your questions are either considered "not constructive" or "off-topic" here so your question is likely to be closed at short notice. As this is a Q&A site, questions have to be objectively answerable, where an *"is A better than B"* question simply can't fit. Also, questions regarding licensing are explicitly considered off-topic as per the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) to avoid the possibility of wrong advice.

Comment: Hi. I don't want to know if HyperV is better than VMWare or other software's out there. I just want to know if the new version has significant improvements from the previous version, and in the scenario of installing a new HyperV Server the 2012 version is the best option. Based on facts you can be objective comparing two versions of a software. Regarding question 2, I already have the license of the product and don't have questions about that. I only wanted to know if I could have more than 4 VM's on a Server Standard, or if that is only possible with the Data Center Edition. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question I would refer you to the [official feature comparison between Hyper-V in 2008R2 and 2012](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/C/A/2CA38362-37ED-4112-86A8-FDF14D5D4C9B/WS%202012%20Feature%20Comparison_Hyper-V.pdf) as published on the Microsoft web site.

Regarding the second question: there is no technical limitation to 4 or 6 virtual machines per host. You will be bound by a [hard limit of 1,024 running VMs per host](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680093.aspx) though. You might be aiming at the licensing terms allowing to run Windows VMs as guests, but licensing questions are explicitly off-topic here. Refer to the [information published by Microsoft on this topic](http://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/about-licensing/virtualization.aspx) and ask your software dealer for advice when in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

For Question 2: Server 2012 Standard allow you to run 2 virtual S2012 servers on the host server 2012. That gives you 1 server and 2 virtual with one key. If you want more, you indeed need the datacenter edition. You can however run more than 2 VM machines on 1 s2012 standard.

Comment: Ok. So, if I have keys for all the VM's I can have the number of VM's I want on a Windows Server Standard Edition? Thanks ;)